# implementing UITextFieldDelegate

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitextfield

I want to use https://github.com/intuit/AnimatedFormFieldTableViewCell in my project but I can’t get my head around the steps for setting it up. So far, I’ve dragged the files from the folder and followed the steps as:

In order to use `AnimatedFormFieldTableViewCell`, all you have to do is:

1) Register the `AnimatedFormFieldTableViewCell` nib on the ViewController on which you are implementing your UITableView for your reuse identifier.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.tableView.registerCellNib(AnimatedFormFieldTableViewCell)

    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

2) Dequeue your cell on CellForRowAtIndexPath as a AnimatedFormFieldTableViewCell.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cellIdentifier = "cell"
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! AnimatedFormFieldTableViewCell

    return cell
}
```

3) Change the placeholder's label text by calling setLabelText on the cell itself.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cellIdentifier = "cell"
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! AnimatedFormFieldTableViewCell

    cell.setLabelText("Enter title")

    return cell
}
```

Notes:

1) You can still implement UITextFieldDelegate the same way you would implement on a regular UITextField, you just need to define the AnimatedFormFieldTableViewCell's delegate (there is no need to directly define the delegate for the embedded UITextField).

2) In order to access the embedded UITextField you can simply call the cell's cellTextField property.

```
I don’t get these last two steps.
```

If I run my app, I get the `unexpectedly found nil` on         `self.cellTextfield.delegate = self` in the `AnimatedFormFieldTableViewCell` class.

What am I missing?

Comment: Where are you accessing `cellTextField`? Can you please include that code as well? The documentation explicitly notes `there is no need to directly define the delegate for the embedded UITextField`. You should likely be setting `self.delegate` to your desired delegate rather than `self.cellTextField.delegate`.

Comment: @MichaelFourre I don’t get that. I’m not accessing `cellTextField`. Nor am I implementing `UITextFieldDelegate`. I don’t know how to. The `self.cellTextField.delegate` that I get error on is implemented in the `AnimatedFormFieldTableViewCell` class and not in mine’s.

Comment: @MichaelFourre Not accessing `cellTextField` is probably why I get the unexpectedly found nil error. But I want to follow the steps sequentially to implement it right.

Comment: Ah okay I get it now. @waseefakhtar let me see if I can figure out what's going on

Comment: @waseefakhtar, I test the `AnimatedFormFieldTableViewCell` in my project, it is ok, so , whats the issue your mean?

Comment: @aircraft can you post how you implemented it? I added my code in the original post and I get the `unexpectedly found nil` error on `self.cellTextField.delegate` in the `AnimatedFormFieldTableViewCell` class.

Comment: @waseefakhtar, bro. first of all, if this is your requirement? http://photo.163.com/liaodalin19903@126/#m=2&aid=307837097&pid=9742550658 . if yes, I will post my code to the answer.

Comment: @aircraft yes, that’s exactly what I want to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My code is here, I don't know where you clerical error, but you can check my code to find out:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController2: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // register a nib like below 
        let nib:UINib = UINib.init(nibName: "AnimatedFormFieldTableViewCell", bundle: nil)

        self.tableView.register(nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "AnimatedFormFieldTableViewCell")

    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 3
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {

        return 88.0
   }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "AnimatedFormFieldTableViewCell", for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! AnimatedFormFieldTableViewCell

        cell.setLabelText("Enter title")

        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
    }

}
```

The result:

[image]

So, just check the steps, where you go wrong.

Comment: Thanks for this. I knew I was looking at a wrong statement for the wrong error, therefore posted all the steps that I’ve implemented. But nobody pointed that I hadn’t registered the nib properly.

Answer (score 2):

Hi [waseefakhtar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2997806/waseefakhtar) your code does not miss anything. just the only problem is you registered the nib with the wrong way that's why you got the `unexpectedly found nil` error on  `self.cellTextfield.delegate = self`.

try this code:

```
  let myNib = UINib.init(nibName: "AnimatedFormFieldTableViewCell", bundle: nil)
  self.tableView.registerNib(myNib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
```

PS: just be aware that registerNib method syntax can differ depending on the swift version

Answer (score 0):

The documentation notes this:

`There is no need to directly define the delegate for the embedded UITextField`

The instruction is to do the following:

`You just need to define the AnimatedFormFieldTableViewCell's delegate`

You'll want to set the `AnimatedFormFieldTableViewCell`'s delegate rather than the `cellTextField`'s delegate, so:

`self.delegate = yourUITextViewDelegate`

rather than `self.cellTextField.delegate = yourUITextViewDelegate` (this is wrong)

This is what the documentation describes

Edit: OP clarified that the delegate assignment code is not in their class; it's in the pod's class. I'm considering deleting this answer as I don't think it is solving the problem.

Comment: And how do I set the `AnimatedFormFieldTableViewCell`’s delegate? In the `viewDidLoad()` where I want to implement it? And what’d be the `yourUITextViewDelegate`?

Comment: You can set the `delegate` in your `UITableViewController`'s `tableView(_:cellForRowAt:)` method by assigning with `cell.delegate = self`. Then you'll want to double check that your `UITableViewController` adopts the `UITextViewDelegate` protocol @waseefakhtar

Comment: So far I’ve added `UITextFieldDelegate` along with the extension for `UITableViewDataSource` and implemented `cell.delegate = self`. If I don’t add the `UITextFieldDelegate`, I get the error: `Cannot assign value of type ‘MyClass' to type 'UITextFieldDelegate?’`

Comment: Yeah that's expected

Comment: I’d still get the same `unexpectedly found nil` error.

Comment: Yes, I don't imagine that setting the delegate solves the nil error. It should solve your concern of "follow the steps sequentially to implement it right"

Comment: I would need more time to look at it.